# How to enable Xamarin app as share target in Xamarin.Forms?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, uiactivityviewcontroller

I have a Xamarin.Forms application that I would like to enable as a text and/or URL share target. I've done this in a Windows UWP app by handling `OnShareTargetActivated`, but I don't see an equivalent in Xamarin.Forms. I am willing to use compiler directives if needed; I would prefer that to doing iOS/Android/Windows specific things in the corresponding projects themselves. Right now all my code is in the Xamarin.Forms project and I'd like to keep it that way.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately Android and Ios do not have a similar share event so there is no equivalent event in xamarin forms.

Comment: I'm not looking for a share event, as if to share from this app, but I want to allow my app to be a share target, and I know that both iOS and Android allow apps to be shared too.

Comment: Would you happen to know then how I could tack on this functionality perhaps by blending some native UI as I know Xamarin can do (but I'm not that familiar with)?